# Pass slice of a value-array to a function as reference

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I need to call a function ([`Matrix.TransformPoints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.transformpoints?view=net-5.0)) which has an array of [`Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=net-5.0) (`PointF`) as a parameter. Unfortunately I only want to apply that function to a slice of that array and I cannot find a function which returns a slice using the original original array as a backing.

It will always be a new array and as both types are structs, it'll copy the values of the `Point`. It would be nice if it would support `Span<T>`, as that would do the trick.

For testing, I've been writing this example. I've added a `DoSpan` function, because then I could verify that `DoArray(Span.ToArray())` doesn't work while `DoSpan(Span)` does. Only when passing the original array to `DoArray` (or using `DoSpan`), it'll actually change the values from the original array.

```
    // Same parameters as Matrix.TransformPoints
    public static void DoArray(Point[] points)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i].X++;
        }
    }

    // Just to verify that with Spans it could work, but not Span.ToArray()
    public static void DoSpan(Span<Point> points)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i].X++;
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Point[] points = new Point[4];
        DoArray(points);
        PrintArray("Complete Array", points);
        DoArray(points[2..4]);
        PrintArray("Array-Slice", points);
        DoSpan(points.AsSpan(2..4));
        PrintArray("Span", points);
        DoArray(points.AsSpan(2..4).ToArray());
        PrintArray("Span.ToArray()", points);
    }
    
    private static void PrintArray(string msg, IEnumerable<Point> points)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        foreach (var p in points)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{p}");
        }
    }
```

Now if I was programming in C, I could just pass the pointer the third element and the function wouldn't know that it is an array slice (of course I'd also need to pass a length/count). So I'm wondering whether C# does have something similar.

Comment: Your `DoSpan(points.AsSpan(2..4))` call works fine for me, which is what I'd expect. The output after that has X values of 1, 1, 2, 2 (where the first call has set them all to 1, and the DoSpan call has incremented indexes 2 and 3 to value 2). So basically: just use spans...

Comment: (But `points[2..4]` will create a new array, and so will calling `ToArray` - so don't do either of those.)

Comment: But `Matrix.TransformPoints` doesn't accept spans.

Comment: I've edited the original post to make it clearer, that the limitation is `Matrix.TransformPoints`.

Comment: Okay, if `Matrix.TransformPoints` *only* accepts an array, then you're stuck.